# why is count(case date) counting null situations aswell?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
COUNT(studentuntil) AS CountNow,
COUNT(case when studentuntil > '2018-6-1' then 1 else 0 end) as Testdate
```

when I do this the results are

CountNow 15

Testdate  60

so when i check CountNow I only have 15 records so that means that Testdate should have 15 or less records, however it is also including the null entries. How do I stop it including the null values?

i tried this aswell

```
COUNT(case when studentuntil > '2018-6-1' and is not null then 1 else 0 end) as testdate
```

also didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `CASE` and fill `ELSE` part with not-nullable value it will be counted.

You could skip `ELSE` part:

```
COUNT(case when studentuntil > '2018-6-1' then 1 end) as Testdate
```

or change `COUNT` to `SUM`:

```
SUM(case when studentuntil > '2018-6-1' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as Testdate
```

---

And in my opinion the best approach:

```
COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE studentuntil > '2018-6-1')
```

Comment: thX, it kept driving me crazy for about 3 hours!

Comment: which postgres version is filter compatible with cause its not for 9.3

Comment: @Tito FILTER was added in 9.4